# I have a problem I created a counter app, and then I added an input field.. But I want what I input in the field to reflect in the count section

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

I want what I input in the input field to reflect on the count and also be able to increase or decrease it(I mean the value inputted)

I created two states... The useState for count and input

Comment: Please share the code with us, otherwise it's hard to tell what the issue is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm currently using my phone so I couldn't post the code here

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to update the counter via input and also with buttons as incremental.

Here is a quick React code below and you can find the sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-surf-0u26i6?file=/src/App.js). If you want to separate the link between the input and the `counter` just remove the line `value={counter}` from inside the `input` tag.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(777);

  const updateNumber = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCounter(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  const upNo = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  const downNo = () => {
    setCounter(counter - 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Input your number</h1>
      <button onClick={downNo}>-</button>
      <input
        value={counter}
        name="mynumber"
        id="mynumber"
        type="number"
        onChange={updateNumber}
      />
      <button onClick={upNo}>+</button>
      <br />
      <h2>My Number: {counter}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can implement this same idea using the useReducer hook?

Comment: IMO, that would be overkill to use `useReducer` since the state update is not complex and you don't have multiple items in the state. Also, that is a whole other question. If you think this is the answer to your question, kindly accept the answer.